# How can I handle input errors in HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have Asp.Net Core Api with Graphql integrated by HotChocolate. I have mutation CreateRoadmap with input type CreateRoadmapInput.
[My Mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLu2K.png).
[My input type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Amb.png).

---

I need to properly validate these input's fields. I tried to use IErrorFilter.[My Error Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR0CL.png) I managed to customize error messages, but it always returns 500 status code and doesn't specify the field that has invalid input value. For example: client may send one field of GraphQl variable as float(with dot and numbers after it). In this case, i got Internal Server Error with status code 500 and the error message. [Response with invalid input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOuiD.png) [Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1cLW.png). Translation from Russian: "Invalid input data: Invalid field value: please enter a integer number"

---

What i want:

1. To give 400(Bad Request) status code in case of invalid input.
2. To specify which field(s) has invalid value

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you understood the question. Thanks for help!

---

My Mutation

```
public ObjectPayload<Roadmap> CreateRoadmap(
        CreateRoadmapInput obj,
        [Service] IServiceFactory<Roadmap> serviceFactory)
    {
        try
        {
            var roadmapService = serviceFactory.CreateServiceInstance(obj.WorkerType);
            var roadmap = roadmapService.Create(obj);

            return new ObjectPayload<Roadmap>(roadmap);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ObjectPayload<Roadmap>(
                new UserError(e.Message, "EXECUTION_ERROR"));
        }
    }
```

---

Mu input type

```
public class CreateRoadmapInput : InputBase
{
    
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public RoadmapType Type { get; set; }
    public int Period { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int ProcessPercent { get; set; }
    public int ProjectPercent { get; set; }
    public WorkerType WorkerType { get; set; }
}
```

---

My error filter

```
public class ErrorHandling : IErrorFilter
{
    public IError OnError(IError error)
    {
        error = error.RemoveExtensions().RemoveLocations().RemoveCode();
        if (error.Message.Contains("got an invalid value"))
        {
            if (error.Exception.Message.Contains("Int cannot parse the given literal of type"))
                return error.WithMessage($"Некорректные вводимые данные: Неверное значение поля. Введите целое число");
            else
                return error.WithMessage($"Некорректные вводимые данные: {error.Exception.Message}");
        }
        return error.WithMessage(error.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Thank you for posting your question. Could you copy the code in the question instead of images ? According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask : "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc". Thanks for your understanding

Comment: Ok, I will copy the code as soon as I get access to my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphql processing pipeline is split into the validation and the execution. As far as I understand, the custom libraries for input validation proposed by Sergey Shaykhullin start taking part in the process only on the execution stage.
But the case with variables you have mentioned is [a part of](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-All-Variable-Usages-are-Allowed) the validation stage.
Actually, the HotChocolate of version 11.2.2 validation engine provides you with all the data you need (i.e. specific error code and variable name) in
the "extensions" field:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Variable `someInt` got an invalid value.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 21
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "HC0016",
                "variable": "someInt",
                "underlyingError": "Int cannot parse the given literal of type `StringValueNode`."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Regarding the second issue with status code 400 then, yes, error 500 is really strange here. I believe error 500 for validation error doesn't conform to the [graphql over http](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-over-http/blob/main/spec/GraphQLOverHTTP.md#document-validation) spec. The spec explicitly states that

> "The server SHOULD deny execution with a status code of 400"

To overcome that issue, you can write [your own result serializer](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/aspnetcore#serialization). In the simplest form, it might be something like the below one:

```
public class HttpResultSerializerWithCustomStatusCodes : DefaultHttpResultSerializer
    {
        public override HttpStatusCode GetStatusCode(IExecutionResult result)
        {
            var baseStatusCode = base.GetStatusCode(result);

            if (result is IQueryResult && baseStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError && result.Errors?.Count > 0)
            {
                if (result.Errors.Any(e => e.Code == ErrorCodes.Authentication.NotAuthorized || e.Code == ErrorCodes.Authentication.NotAuthenticated))
                    return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;    

                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;    

            }

            return baseStatusCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. I'll try to write my own result serializer to return 400 status code in case of troubles with GraphQL var. There is no way to work with 500 code status  - fronters will eat me alive. I'll write down here results as soon as i'll do it properly

Comment: Yes, there might be issues with that code on the client frameworks, like, for instance, on apollo client. Btw, what client framework (if any) you use is facing the issues with graphql server status 500 returning?

Comment: We are using Apollo client for graphQl.

Comment: As well as we do. Do you, guys, facing issues regarding errors 4xx from graphql server all go to networkErrors which is bad for proper handling of validation errors?

Comment: Fronters said that they didn't have troubles like that.

Comment: @ШаукатХайруллин Founded any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of community maintained packages for input validation

https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/develop/COMMUNITY.md#validation

Or write your own by provided code examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like it can solve my problem. I'll write in comments results after implementing on of the validation libraries

Comment: Hi! I used one of these libraries( one named Graph.ArgumentValidation). It helped me to validate inputs that wrote in query body, but not in GraphQL Variable field. It throws exception lower on caller stack - in parsing part(if I understood properly). Problem is that I can’t get the field filled wrong. It only says about parsing problems(example: something like that “Int can’t parse given literal value of type Float”). I tried to look to the all libraries source code and noticed that all of their middlewares catches request only after parsing that was already failed.

Comment: I talked about this problem with my more experienced colleagues and they said that seems like that  there is no solution that we need doesn’t exist for now.